# React-router v4: Conditional expression not executing correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

OS: Windows 10 Pro
React-router: 4.1.1
React: 15.5.4

So, I'm doing a conditional check in a `<Route />` to ascertain whether an authToken exists, and if it does not to redirect a user to login,  otherwise render an associated component. But even though the token exists, as can be seen in the image, the user still gets redirected to the login page if you do a page reload of root `/` or `/view/:postId`.

What am I overlokking here?

app.js

```html
  render () {
    const SOME_PATH = window.location.pathname;

    return (
      <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route path={SOME_PATH} component={App}/>
        </Router>
      </ApolloProvider>
    )
  }
```

App.js

```html
export default compose(
  allPostsCommentsQuery,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Main);
```

Main.js

```html
  render () {
    const auth = this.props.auth.token;
    console.log('auth = ', auth);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Link to="/">Flamingo City</Link>
        </h1>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}`} exact render={(props) => (
            !auth ? <Redirect to="/login"/> : <PhotoGrid {...this.props} {...props} />
          )} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}view/:postId`} render={(props) => (
            !auth ? <Redirect to="/login"/> : <Single {...this.props} {...props} />
          )} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}login`} render={(props) => (
            <LoginUser {...this.props} {...props} />
          )} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: i have same issue

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring the code as follows resolved the issue:

```
!auth ? (<Redirect to="/login"/>) : (<PhotoGrid {...this.props} {...props} />)
```